# ISupportIncrementalLoading Collection - notify UI when LoadingMoreItems is in progress

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, message, statusbar

I've have created a `IncrementalLoadingCollection` class in my app which implements `ISupportIncrementalLoading` and inherits from `ObservableCollection< T >`.

It works fine and the items are loaded but I would like to show a message on the app's `Status Bar` that there is some work in progress.

What's a good way of achieving this?

Since `LoadMoreItemsAsync` is called internally when the list is scrolled, I cannot access that part to come up with the code which updates the `Status Bar`. Right now, I am doing this in `LoadMoreItemsAsync` which I find it a terrible approach, but I couldn't find a better one so far...

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can for example: inherit from `ObservableCollection` and implement `ISupportIncrementalLoading` like this:

```
class IncrementalLoadingObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    private readonly Func<CancellationToken, Task<IEnumerable<T>>> _provideMoreItems;

    public IncrementalLoadingObservableCollection(Func<CancellationToken, Task<IEnumerable<T>> provideMoreItems)
    {
        _provideMoreItems = provideMoreItems;
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        return AsyncInfo.Run(async cancelToken =>
        {
            await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                OnLoadMoreItemsStarted();
            });

            var providedItems = await _provideMoreItems(cancelToken);

            await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                foreach(var item in providedItems)
                    Add(item);

                OnLoadMoreItemsCompleted();
            });

            return new LoadMoreItemsResult {Count = (uint) providedItems.Count()};;
        });
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public event Action LoadMoreItemsStarted;
    public event Action LoadMoreItemsCompleted;

    protected virtual void OnLoadMoreItemsStarted()
    {
        var handler = LoadMoreItemsStarted;
        if (handler != null) handler();
    }

    protected virtual void OnLoadMoreItemsCompleted()
    {
        var handler = LoadMoreItemsCompleted;
        if (handler != null) handler();
    }
}
```

How to use it? In your ViewModel:

```
class MyFancyItemsViewModel
{
     public MyFancyItemsViewModel()
     {  
         var incrementalObservablCollcetion = new IncrementalLoading...(GetItemsFromInternetOrSmth);
         incrementalObservablCollcetion.LoadMoreItemsStarted += OnItemsLoadingStarted;
         incrementalObservablCollcetion.LoadMoreItemsCompleted += OnItemsLoadingCompleted;

          ItemsBindedInXaml = incrementalObservablCollcetion;
     }

     private Task<IEnumerable<Items>> GetItemsFromInternetOrSmth(CancellationToken cancelToken)
     {
      ... do some work returns enumerable of Items
     }

     private void OnItemsLoadingStarted()
     { .. do smth .. }

     private void OnItemsLoadingCompleted()
     { ... do smth .. } 

     public ObservableCollection<Items> ItemsBindedInXaml { get; private set; }
}
```

You might ask why I have used `Dispatcher.RunAsync` in `IncrementalLoadingObservableCollection` - the reason is that `LoadMoreItemsAsync` might run on another thread (don't know that) so you have to dispatch all the work to the `UI Thread` (it's not possible to call UI-related methods from thread other than `UI thread` without use of `Dispatcher`).

If you feel that `ViewModel` is not appropiate place for UI-related operations take a look at some messaging mechanisms (like `MVVM Light Messenger`, register message in code-behind and send this message in `LoadMoreItemsStarted` handler)

Comment: This approach of using events is absolutely great, I love it! I was already using the dispatcher to go back on the UI with the message but I wasn't satified at all because of a terrible coupling. If only I could vote this answer multiple times :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems though that the notification occurs only once, at the first call... I have made an edit. The code in the handlers are executed as the breakpoints are hit, but nothing is shown on the UI...

Comment: @VasileF that's not error related to IncrementalObservableCollection - when OnCompleted is called "StatusBar.HideAsync" is called (according to your code) which means StatusBar will be closed until you call "StatusBar.ShowAsync". So you need to call: await statusBar.ShowAsync(); before you show progress indiciator

Comment: @Vasilef I'd rather go with StatusBar.ProgressIndicator.HideAsync in Completed event handler.