# Incremental loading with progress ring

Tags: c#, progress-bar, lazy-loading

I have implemented incremental loading in my application, and it has `isLoading` bool variable, which is set to true in constructor and set to false, when `hasMoreItems` is setto false. And I have `ProgressRing` which works like this:

```
private void List_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
{
    if (list.Items.Count == 0 && list.ItemsSource == null)
        CenterProgressRing.IsActive = true;
    else if (list.Items.Count == 0 && list.ItemsSource != null) 
    {
        if (!((IncrementalSource)this.list.ItemsSource).isLoading)
            CenterProgressRing.IsActive = false; 
        else CenterProgressRing.IsActive = true;
    }
    else CenterProgressRing.IsActive = false;        
}
```

So it is showing `ProgressRing` while first page is loading, and it works very good, when there are items to receive. But when it comes to situations when there is nothing to load, `ProgressRing` keeps being active forever. I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, simplify your conditions (remove nesting and negation).

```
if (list.ItemsSource == null)
{
    CenterProgressRing.IsActive = false;
    return;
}
CenterProgressRing.IsActive = ((IncrementalSource)this.list.ItemsSource).isLoading;
```

Then it might not work if `List_LayoutUpdated` is not called after your last item is downloaded (as layout is not updated). Probably, you may update `CenterProgressRing.IsActive` in you `IncrementalSource` (if you implement an event or make `isLoading` observable) or make sure List_LayoutUpdated after the last item is downloaded.

Comment: You were right about `List_LayoutUpdated` not being called after last item is downloaded. Making `isLoading` observable didn't help either. But adding action/event as suggested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870079/isupportincrementalloading-collection-notify-ui-when-loadingmoreitems-is-in-pr) did the work. Anyway, thank you for your contribution, and I will mark your answer as accepted answer.